# How to access gestures on screen in background

Tags: flutter

Basically I am building a music player application.
I want to incorporate an extra feature that can recognize any gesture on the screen even if the phone is on sleep mode.

For example, if you want to play/pause the song then you can just tap 3 times on the phone screen.

First, let me know which one is possible.

1. The phone is on sleep and the application is opened in the background and then you perform some gestures.
2. The phone is on sleep and the application is removed from the background and then you perform some gesture.

I know this functionality needs some coding on the native side.
I just want to know what should be my approach to this?